# Pop up text box

Tags: html, css, popup

I'd like to know how is called the box that pops up and overlays on top of a webpage.

Examples are: 
Facebook photos - It grays the background webpage and opens a separate pop up to view pictures.

Advertisements - The box that you (often) have to click the 'x' to get out.

Basically it is on the same page but it shows up in the middle, on top of your main webpage for critical information or not.

I'd like to create one to explain what the webpage is supposed to be about, sort of an orientation, or when a person requests it; for example, by clicking "learn more".

Comment: you can make just about any element do that with the right styles, but its common to use a div, using css styles to change its position, z-index, opacity, etc

Comment: So that means I make an onclick event for the [learn more] text to call a function that calls the css and make the body black with opacity and show the div in the right position?

Comment: I've heard them referred as a "lightbox"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following is a simple way of doing a overlay popup. Note that some of this might be easier to do with a library like jQuery or jQuery's UI library which makes it real easy to make a dialog box. There are other libraries like lightbox etc. But the below is using pure javascript.

Also note that i have comments in the CSS code, so you know what each part is doing.

```js
//Use the onload event so that we can make sure the DOM is at 
//least mostly loaded before trying to get elements
window.onload = function() {
   //Get the DOM element that represents the <button> element.
   //And set the onclick event
   document.getElementById("LearnMoreBtn").onclick = function(){
      //Set a variable to contain the DOM element of the overly
      var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
      //Set a variable to contain the DOM element of the popup
      var popup = document.getElementById("popup");
      
      //Changing the display css style from none to block will make it visible
      overlay.style.display = "block";
      //Same goes for the popup
      popup.style.display = "block";
   };
};
```

```css
#overlay {
   display:none;    /* This make it initially hidden                                           */
   position:fixed;  /* This makes it so it says in a fixed position even if they scroll around */
   left:0px;        /* This positions the element to the left most position                    */
   top:0px;         /* This positions the elment to the top most position                      */
   width:100%;      /* This makes the element take up 100% of the parents width                */
   height:100%;     /* This makes the element take up 100% of the parents height               */
   background:#000; /* Give it a black background                                              */
   opacity:0.5;     /* Change the opacity to 50% so that is see through.                       */
   z-index:99999;   /* Change the z-index so it will be above everything else                  */
}

#popup {
   display:none;
   position:fixed;
   left:50%;              /* left and top here position top left page                                        */
   top:50%;               /* of the element to the center of the                                             */
   width:300px;           /* Set the popup to have a specific width/height                                   */
   height:150px;
   margin-top:-75px;      /* To get the popup to center correctly we need                                    */
   margin-left:-150px;    /* To displace the the top/left margins by half of the width/height                */
   background:#FFFFFF;    /* Background of white                                                             */
   border:2px solid #000; /* And give it a border                                                            */
   z-index:100000;        /* Set z-index to 1 more than that of the overlay so the popup is over the overlay */
}
```

```html
<button id="LearnMoreBtn">Learn More</button>
<div id="overlay"></div>
<div id="popup">
  Popup contents here
</div>
```

To hide the overlay and the popup again just set the `.style.display` back to `none`

```
overlay.style.display = "none";
popup.style.display = "none";
```

Note that using this particular code will make the overlay and popup abruptly appear, no fading or sliding. As I mentioned earlier it would be easier to do these kind of things with the libraries mentioned among others.

Answer (score 1):

The general functionality of what you're looking for is called a modal dialog.

Here's a demo for the jqueryui control: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-message

Answer (score 0):

An easier way is to use the `title` attribute, it is available for any element and almost in every browser it shows a tooltip for you. Here there are some more examples:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_title.asp